# Calculus - Volume of Solid of Revolutions

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

Find the volume of the figure enclosed by

$\begin{cases}
y = \ln 5x \\
y=3\\
y=4\\
x=0\\
\end{cases}$

and rotated about the $y$-axis.

I came up with the following integral in terms of $y$:

$$\int_3^4 \pi \left(\dfrac{e^y}{5} \right) ^2dy$$

but the approximate answer of $161.95$ is incorrect. I asked a tutor at my university and they came up with the same answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is supposed to be $$\frac{\pi}{50}(e^{8}-e^{6}).$$

Comment: Assuming you've stated the problem correctly, you and your tutor are right and the answer key is wrong. (Or maybe they want more digits  or a symbolic answer if it's a computer submission?)

Comment: @vaponteblizzard I seem to get the answer you have provided too. However, would you mind stating what the answer key says so that we can see why it may be the case?

Comment: It was indeed a computer submission so I don't have an answer key. I finally was marked right after simplifying some terms in the exact answer. Usually, simplification is not necessary which is why I tried decimal form when it didn't work the first time. I was seriously starting to doubt myself!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. I went ahead and found the volume using the [cylinder method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution#Cylinder_method) and I arrived at the same answer.

Note that $y=3$ intersects $\ln 5x$ at $(4.017, \ 3)$ and $y=4$ intersects it at $(10.92, \ 4)$, which you can see here on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fapaqcexr3). Using this, we have:

$$ \displaystyle{2 \pi \int_0^{10.92} (4x) \ dx - 2\pi \int_{4.017}^{10.92} (x \ln 5x ) \ dx - 2\pi \int_0^{4.017} (3x) \ dx } $$
$$=161.951$$

Comment: It's refreshing to see it confirmed with the shell method! As I said in my comment above, it was a particularly persnickety computer submission. Thanks for the help.